# Outlook-iPhone and private email

Tags: email, ms-office, iphone

How can I send private email from my iphone to an Outlook user so his delegates cannot see the email?

Comment: Super User is not for questions about mobile devices as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the permissions of the Delegate so they can not see private items. Here's a KB article about granting permission to them:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249324

The trick is now finding a way to get your iPhone to add the "Private" flag to your message. I don't have an iPhone so I can't help you there. Just edit the properties of your message and see what you can change.